# What is the NT significance of Exodus 29:21?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 29:21
New International Version

> And take some **blood** from the altar and some of the **anointing oil** and sprinkle it on Aaron and his **garments** and on his sons and their **garments**. Then he and his sons and their **garments** will be consecrated.

I'm particularly interested in the combination of blood and oil.

Comment: Please clarify : Does "the-blood" הַדָּ֨ם specifically from the אֵ֥יל מִלֻּאִ֖ים "Ram-[of]-Ordination" get referenced in the New Testament? -- Since the "wine" referenced in Matthew 26:28 would represent the bull's blood from exodus 29:14 (not the blood from the Ram-of-Ordination).

Comment: Does "the-blood" הַדָּ֨ם specifically from the אֵ֥יל מִלֻּאִ֖ים "Ram-[of]-Ordination" get referenced in the New Testament? Sorry, I do not know.

Comment: Are you asking if any reference to "Blood" in the NT was anything other than a metaphorical sin offering? * How does the distinct blood of the אֵ֥יל מִלֻּאִ֖ים "Ram-[of]-Ordination" get referenced at all in the NT?

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for an explicit direct reference of that in the NT. It could be a metaphorical reference.

Comment: Are you asking if Priests in the order of מַלְכִּי־צֶֽדֶק Malkitsedeq received the Levitical Ordination in the New Testament? - Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Not specifically.

Comment: Then why does your question allude specifically to Ordination of Levitical kohanim in reference to blood from the Ram of Ordination from Exodus 29:21-22?

Comment: not specifically on Malkitsedeq. But if you wish to interpret it that way, I'm open to your idea and I'll upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**What is the NT significance of Exodus 29:21?**

- **None.** | Levitical Ordination does not apply to Jesus of Nazareth. - Since the NT [Hebrews 5:5-6 / Hebrews 7:11-12] claims Jesus of Nazareth was a priest in the order of " Μελχισέδεκ ".

Malkitsedeq מַלְכִּי־צֶֽדֶק was not a son of Aharon, which means Jesus of Nazareth's order referenced in NT **[Hebrews 7:11-12]**  would not require blood from the אֵ֥יל מִלֻּאִ֖ים Ram-[of]-Ordination in Exodus 29:20-22. **This type of Ordination blood was only for אַהֲרֹ֧ן וּבָנָ֛יו Aharon & His-sons.**

Comment: The writer to the Hebrews states that 'we have a great high priest ... Jesus the Son of God.' Hebrews 4:14. Now Melchisedec was but one. Only the Aaronic priesthood had a 'high' priest (above other priests). Therefore the Aaronic priesthood may be taken as being symbolic of the priesthood of Jesus _as well as_ the priesthood of Melchisedec which has _other_ symbols of Jesus priesthood. So great is the Priesthood of Jesus Christ that no one figure can adequately portray the vast scale. Therefore different aspects must be employed to express thoroughly different concepts.

Comment: @NigelJ - Does context never matter in Biblical Hermenuetics?

Comment: Correct! Simple, concise, and supported.

Answer (score 1):

#### What is the NT significance of Exodus 29:21?

The article "[Empowering a Priesthood for Effectual Service](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1968483#h=7)" from the *Watchtower* July 1, 1968 issue has the following about the verse:

> The spattering of the mixture of blood from the altar and oil upon Aaron and his sons and their garments served to sanctify them. This seems to speak of a more effectual priesthood whose identification and authority from God would be marked by a spirit-filled ministry and whose acceptance with God is founded upon strong faith in the precious sacrifice of Christ Jesus. Both persons and garments being spattered suggests that the members of this priesthood, individually and collectively, inwardly and outwardly, must be identified as depending fully upon the merit of Christ’s atoning blood and bringing forth the rich fruitage of Jehovah’s holy spirit.

So, the blood would have been foreshadowing the blood Christ shed and his sacrifice for mankind.

The anointing oil would be a physical representation of Jehovah God choosing the Levites just as when a new king was chosen for the nation of Israel. ([1 Samuel 16:13](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/9/16#s=13&study=discover&v=9:16:13); [1 Kings 16:39](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/11/1#study=discover&v=11:1:39))

Answer (score 1):

This has a relationship to John 6:52-60.  Without getting caught up the the discussion about whether communion is the literal body and blood of Christ, but focus on what those listening to Jesus thought, Eli Lizorkin-Eyzenberg gives one of the best answers when commenting on John 6:52-60.

> **Animal blood was symbolically poured on the altar of the Jerusalem Temple to make atonement for the Israelites. It was meant for God. It was meant to be consumed by Him and by Him alone**. This may sound strange to modern ears, but this is exactly how the ancients thought of sacrifice. The ancient Israelites were not exceptional in this understanding of sacrifice. They offered God food for holy consumption.... But in the ancient mind, the slaughtered sacrifice was meant to symbolize a fully dedicated life offered to the deity worshipped. No questions asked.

> So, what is happening here? I think it is something like this – Jesus says: **“Now the tables will be turned. It is God’s turn to offer you all that He is. Just as you offer him the sacrifices symbolizing the whole life, so is he offering you Himself in the person of his Son.”** ...

> Therefore, when Jesus referred to his body and blood, he meant the bread and wine should become, in the minds and hearts of his followers, fully associated with him in the entire spectrum of his life – his person, his teachings and his works. In other words, Jesus expected to be fully understood and received through active participation by faith. By faith in Him, the believer would partake of salvation, which is found in Jesus alone and is offered freely to all.

> So let me summarize. Jesus’ statement about his body and blood is true and no other picture could have made it clearer. **His flesh and his blood, meaning Jesus Himself – the whole Jesus – is the only thing that can sustain a human being to life everlasting**. (Jn. 1: 1, 14) --
> Lizorkin-Eyzenberg, Eli. The Jewish Gospel of John: Discovering Jesus, King of All Israel (pp. 105-106). Jewish Studies for Christians. Kindle Edition.

St. Augustine also answered:

> The hard saying cannot be taken literally, says Augustine, since it would seem to be enjoining a crime or a vice: “it is therefore a figure, bidding us communicate in the sufferings of our Lord, and secretly and profitably treasure in our hearts the fact that his flesh was crucified and pierced for us.” Elsewhere he sums the matter up in an epigram: Crede et manducasti, “Believe, and thou hast eaten.”
> --
> Kaiser, W. C., Jr., Davids, P. H., Bruce, F. F., & Brauch, M. T. (1996). Hard sayings of the Bible (p. 500). Downers Grove, IL: InterVarsity.

Here is a summary related to communion:

> In the discourse of John 6 Jesus is not making a direct reference to Holy Communion, but this discourse conveys the same truth in words as Holy Communion conveys in action. This truth is summed up in the invitation extended to the communicant in the Book of Common Prayer: “Take and eat this in remembrance that Christ died for thee, and feed on him in thy heart by faith with thanksgiving.” To feed on Christ in one’s heart by faith with thanksgiving is to “eat the flesh of the Son of Man and drink his blood” and so have eternal life.
> --
> Kaiser, W. C., Jr., Davids, P. H., Bruce, F. F., & Brauch, M. T. (1996). Hard sayings of the Bible (p. 500). Downers Grove, IL: InterVarsity.

Answer (score 1):

As Messiah, Jesus had many functions which included:

- **High Priest**, Heb 4:14, 15, 5:10, 6:20, 7:26, 28, 8:2, 9:11, 10:12, 21, etc.
- **Prophet**, Deut 18:15, 18-20, Acts 3:21-23
- **King**, Luke 1:32, 33, John 1:49, Matt 1:1, 20, 9:27, 12:23, 15:22, 20:30, 15, 21:9, 15, Mark 10:35, Luke 1:32, 33, 18:38, 39, John 1:49, Acts 13:32-37, Heb 1:8, etc.
- **The sacrifice of the New Covenant**, John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 12:1-14).  Thus, He provides the blood of the New covenant of which the communion is a memorial, Matt 26:28, Mark 14:24, Luke 22:20, 1 Cor 11:25, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 24:5, 8).

The anointing oil of dedication was applied in the OT economy to **Kings** (1 Sam 15:1, 2 Sam 2:4, 1 Kings 1:34, 5:1, 19:16, Judges 9:8, etc.), **prophets** (1 Chron 16:22, 1 Kings 19:16, 1 Chron 16:22, etc), and **priests** (Ex 29:7, 40:12-15, etc) to set them apart for a special function - to represent the coming Messiah.

The book of Hebrews in most of its chapters compares the high priest in the OT sanctuary/temple as a type of Jesus.

Thus, Jesus was a worthy antitype of the anointing oil as prophet, priest and king, as well as the blood as the the antitype of the sacrificial Passover lamb.